# Word to Excel Macro - Unable to Transpose

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on building out a Macro that takes information from Word and opens it in a new Excel Document. This is a Word macro that starts in Word.

```
Sub Exportwordtoexcel()
Dim wordDoc As Object
Dim oXL As Excel.Application
Dim DocTarget As Word.Document
Dim Target As Excel.Workbook
Dim tSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set wordDoc = GetObject(, "word.application")
wordDoc.Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Copy

On Error Resume Next
Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If Err Then
ExcelWasNotRunning = True
Set oXL = New Excel.Application
End If

oXL.Visible = True

Set Target = oXL.Workbooks.Add
Set tSheet = Target.Sheets(1)
tSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

When I run this macro, it places my header in A1 which is what I want. It will then place my first paragraph in A2 which also what I want. Unfortunately, it places the next paragraph in A3 when I would like to paste it in B2. The correct flow is as follows:

- Header - A1
- Paragraph 1 - A2
- Paragraph 2 - B2
- Paragraph 3 - A3
- Paragraph 4 - B3

and so on for as many paragraphs as I'm using....

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: You are assuming Excel can deduce how to insert your paragraphs without you providing any information on the layout you want.  As you haven't provided any instructions on where to place individual paragraphs, Excel is using its own internal rules.  To provide your instructions you will have to replace  you current copy and paste with code that iterates through each paragraph and then places the paragraphs appropriately in word.

Comment: Actually I just tried this code on a random document and it pasted it fine so I suspect it may be an issue with the original document.

Comment: @Freeflow Would you be able to help on the paragraph iteration piece? I have no idea where to get started.

Comment: Given that your code starts in Word, your source document is probably the ActiveDocument of which you want to transfer much more than the current Selection. Further given that `Select` is to be avoided, the first 3 lines of your code make next to no sense. Given that you want to transfer text from the document to an Excel table it stands to reason that this should be easier if the source document would contain a table. In fact, you could transform source text to a table before you copy it. So, the source could be `ActiveDocument.Tables(1)`. The Excel part of your code seems to be working.